# How can I decode and deserialize json from 'the movie db' using VIPER?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, viper-architecture

I'm learning how to display data in a tableview through 'the movie db' api using the VIPER architecture but I still haven't learned how to decode and serialize JSON. I share my classes.

**The JSON Response**

```
    {
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/aTovumsNlDjof7YVoU5nW2RHaYn.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                27,
                53,
                10749
            ],
            "id": 616820,
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Halloween Ends",
            "overview": "Four years after the events of Halloween in 2018, Laurie has decided to liberate herself from fear and rage and embrace life. But when a young man is accused of killing a boy he was babysitting, it ignites a cascade of violence and terror that will force Laurie to finally confront the evil she can’t control, once and for all.",
            "popularity": 4845.496,
            "poster_path": "/3uDwqxbr0j34rJVJMOW6o8Upw5W.jpg",
            "release_date": "2022-10-12",
            "title": "Halloween Ends",
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 6.9,
            "vote_count": 417
        },
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/5GA3vV1aWWHTSDO5eno8V5zDo8r.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                27,
                53
            ],
            "id": 760161,
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Orphan: First Kill",
            "overview": "After escaping from an Estonian psychiatric facility, Leena Klammer travels to America by impersonating Esther, the missing daughter of a wealthy family. But when her mask starts to slip, she is put against a mother who will protect her family from the murderous “child” at any cost.",
            "popularity": 3138.264,
            "poster_path": "/pHkKbIRoCe7zIFvqan9LFSaQAde.jpg",
            "release_date": "2022-07-27",
            "title": "Orphan: First Kill",
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 6.8,
            "vote_count": 1046
        },
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/etP5jwlwvkNhwe7jnI2AyA6ZKrR.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                878
            ],
            "id": 575322,
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Звёздный разум",
            "overview": "After depleting Earth's resources for centuries, humankind's survival requires an exodus to outer space. An international expedition is quickly formed to find a suitable new planet, but when plans go awry, the crew is suddenly stranded without power on a strange planet, where something unimaginable lies in wait.",
            "popularity": 2457.191,
            "poster_path": "/aVLV38txajXhEy2qNEClPIsDbAH.jpg",
            "release_date": "2022-01-06",
            "title": "Project Gemini",
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 5.5,
            "vote_count": 98
        }
    ],
    "total_pages": 35518,
    "total_results": 710341
}
```

**InteractorTMDB**

```
import Foundation


protocol AnyInteractor{
    
    var presenter : AnyPresenter? {get set}
    
    func downloadMovies()
    
}

class MovieInteractor : AnyInteractor {
    var presenter : AnyPresenter?
    
    func downloadMovies(){
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=115962553d2044ca5dd8433fb4bc3e29")
        else{
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                self?.presenter?.interactorDidDownloadMovie(result:
                        .failure(NetworkError.networkFailed))
                return
            }
            do{
                let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Result].self, from: data)
                self?.presenter?.interactorDidDownloadMovie(result: .success(movies))
            }catch{
                self?.presenter?.interactorDidDownloadMovie(result: .failure(NetworkError.parsingFailed))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

**PresenterTMDB**

```
import Foundation

enum NetworkError : Error {
    
    case networkFailed
    case parsingFailed
    
}

protocol AnyPresenter {
    
    var router : AnyRouter? {get set}
    var interactor : AnyInteractor? {get set}
    var view : AnyView? {get set}
    
    func interactorDidDownloadMovie(result: Result<Movies: [Results], Error>)
    
}

class MoviePresenter : AnyPresenter {
    
    var router: AnyRouter?
    
    var interactor : AnyInteractor? {
        didSet{
            interactor?.downloadMovies()
        }
    }
    var view: AnyView?
    
    func interactorDidDownloadMovie(result: Result<Movies: [Results], Error>){
        switch result{
        case .success(let movies):
            view?.update(with: movies)
        case.failure(_):
            view?.update(with: "Intenta más tarde")
        }
    }
}
```

**EntityTMDB**

```
import Foundation


struct Movies: Codable {
    let page: Int
    let results: [Results]
    let totalPages, totalResults: Int

}

struct Results: Codable {
    let adult: Bool
    let backdropPath: String
    let genreIDS: [Int]
    let id: Int
    let originalTitle, overview: String
    let popularity: Double
    let posterPath, releaseDate, title: String
    let video: Bool
    let voteAverage: Double
    let voteCount: Int

}
```

**RouterTMDB**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

typealias EntryPoint = AnyView & UIViewController

protocol AnyRouter{
    var entry: EntryPoint? {get}
    static func startExecution() -> AnyRouter
}

class MovieRouter : AnyRouter {
    var entry : EntryPoint?
    
    static func startExecution() -> AnyRouter {
        let router = MovieRouter()
        
        var view: AnyView = ViewTMDB() as! AnyView
        var presenter : AnyPresenter = MoviePresenter()
        var interactor : AnyInteractor = MovieInteractor()
        view.presenter = presenter
        
        presenter.view = view
        presenter.router = router
        presenter.interactor = interactor
        interactor.presenter = presenter
        router.entry = view as? EntryPoint
        
        return router
    }
}
```

I really don't know how to show this JSON response in a tableview using VIPER architecture.

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to decode a Result struct but you didn't _show_ us any Result struct, so it's impossible to know whether you've defined it correctly. — Note that this question is way over-engineered. It has nothing to do with VIPER. Just show the Json, the Result and any related types, and the `decode` command that's not working.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the `Codable` protocol. For deserializing objects from JSON you'll specifically want the `Decodable` protocol.

There are simple steps you take to make your structures conform to the Decodable protocol, and then you use an instance of the `JSONDecoder` class to decode your object.

How to display your data in a table view, using VIPER or not, is a separate question. (And I would suggest running away from VIPER as fast as you can. It isn't a design pattern I recommend.)